# Embed Signature Image in SMTP mail via Python

Tags: python

I am trying to send mail by a python script and facing some issues with adding the signature image of the company. I tried to base64 encode the image and then add it in the code like this:

```
Cheers!<br/>

<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{}" alt="image"high="100" width="100" />

XXXX XXX<br/>
  Head of XXXXX<br/>
  XXXX  | XXXX.com<br/>""".format(encoded_string)
```

but in the mail it is showing the broken image

Comment: Technically speaking, the MIME type for JPEG images is `image/jpeg`.  Spelling matters.  Do you really have `high`?  Or do you actually have `height`?

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried `height` but still the same output and the image type is `PNG`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, I did. `<img src="data:image/png;base64,{}" alt="image" height="100" width="100" /><br/>`

Comment: Not all email apps support data-embedded images.  https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/embedded-images-in-html-email/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Python EmailMessage Library this is how I was able to add both a signature in HTML accompanied by an image at the bottom. In my case, I was copying the signature I use in Outlook for automated smtp emails.

```
import codecs
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import make_msgid

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'This is the subject'
msg['From'] = 'email@email.com'
msg['To'] = 'receiver@email.com'
msg['Cc'] = 'cc@email.com'

body = "This is the normal text body of the email"
msg.set_content(body)

# Signature
img_path = r'filepath/sig_img.png'  # Path to img you are appending to the end of the email
html_path = r'htmlpath/signature.htm'  # Path to HTML file for signature (you can just write the HTML code in as well). 

html_file = codecs.open(html_path, 'r', 'utf-8', errors='ignore')  # Opens HTML file and converts to UTF-8, ignoring errors
html_code = html_file.read()  # Writes contents of HTML signature file to a string
html_file.close()

image_id = make_msgid()

# Combines the text body, HTML signature, and image in Email HTML format
msg.add_alternative(body + '<br><br>' + html_code + '<img src="%s" />' % image_id.strip('<>'), subtype='html')

with open(img_path, 'rb') as img:  # Open signature image used in email
    msg.get_payload()[1].add_related(img.read(), 'image', 'png', cid=image_id)

    with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.emailHost.com', 587) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls()
    smtp.login('email', 'pass')

    smtp.send_message(msg)
```

The code used for attaching an image is shown in the [asparagus example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)  on the email lib documentation.